# When I tap the "next" button it pauses the music instead of automatically going to the next song

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I recently implemented a play/pause button which works perfectly using MPMusicPlayerController I have now added a "next song" button. But when I click this "next song" button it pauses the music and when I tap the "play" button then it plays the next song. I was wondering if there was a way where as I click the "next song" button it would automatically play the next song instead of pausing it. Heres my code for the 2 buttons:

```
var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

@IBAction func nextMusicTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    musicPlayer.skipToNextItem()
    musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    musicPlayer.play()
    
}


@IBAction func playPauseMusicTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let state = musicPlayer.playbackState.rawValue
    if (state == 1) { //playing
        musicPlayer.pause()
        musicPlayPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
        musicNextButton.isHidden = true
    } else if (state == 2) { //paused
        musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        musicPlayer.play()
        musicPlayPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
        musicNextButton.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, according to Apple's documentation, `skipToNextItem()` does the following:

> Starts playback of the next media item in the playback queue; or, if the music player is not playing, designates the next media item as the next to be played.

So in other words, if the music player is already playing a song, you shouldn't have to tell it to play the next item, it should automatically start playing. So you wouldn't need the following lines:

```
musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
musicPlayer.play()
```

This also leads me to believe that somehow your music player is being paused prior to that `skipToNextItem()` being called. Try putting `print(musicPlayer.playbackState.rawValue)` before line 4. If it prints `2`, then your music player seems to pause by clicking the "next song" button, so that would mean something weird is going on with your IBAction connections. I've done this before where I accidentally call two different IBAction methods with the same button (due to an error in setting up the outlets in the first place). In your particular case, you could be accidentally calling both the `playPauseMusicTapped` (which pauses the music), and the `nextMusicTapped()` method to switch the songs, but that's just a random thought. Let me know what that playback state before line 4 is, regardless. That would be good to know.

Comment: Hi thank you so much I forgot when I copied and pasted the playpausebutton to make the next song button to unlink the next song button to the playpausemusictapped ibaction.

Comment: Yep that'll do it. Glad I could help!