# iOS twice click for music controller to start

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have music app and I have fully implementation for background but I found one bug when I refactor my design with SwiftUI. When I click pause in my music app and go to backround and try click to play from native iOS music controller I need click twice for play.... And I can't find why? then when it starts playing everything works fine

maybe someone faced a similar problem?

Comment: This is just a random guess (since you don't provide much detail) but it could be something with your IBAction connections? (see [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193217/when-i-tap-the-next-button-it-pauses-the-music-instead-of-automatically-going/66201151#66201151)

Comment: the problem arose when i started using SWIFT. I will share more information